# Excel VBA Pivot Table Filter

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a VBA code for Microsoft Excel to filter our a few items out of many (e.g. 3 items out of 100) from a pivot table. So far the method I've been using is by declaring items I do not want to be false such as:

```
.PivotItems("Item A").Visible = True
.PivotItems("Item B").Visible = True
.PivotItems("Item C").Visible = False
.PivotItems("Item D").Visible = False
.PivotItems("Item E").Visible = False
```

However this gets tedious in the future as there maybe more items added to the table and which means I would need to edit the codes every time there is a new item added.

Is there a way to filter out two or more items without using

```
.Visible=false
```

such as

```
pf.CurrentPage = "Item A" + "Item B"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array of items:

```
Dim arr() As Variant

' Array of items to be kept visible (or hidden depending on your code)
arr = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 2")

For Each itm In pt.PivotFields("Value").PivotItems
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(itm.Caption, arr, 0)) Then
        itm.Visible = True
    Else
        itm.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adapt pivot table and field names but this works on my test:

```
Sub filter_pivot()
    Dim i As Integer
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CLCL")
        For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
            Debug.Print .PivotItems(i)
            Select Case .PivotItems(i).Name
                Case Is = "Item C"
                    .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
                Case Is = "Item D"
                    .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
                Case Is = "Item E"
                    .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

We're still using `.Visible` but it does not matter how many new items you add.